# How to restrict the type of react component passed as prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have 2 components here. Media and Heading

**Media.tsx**

```
export const Media = ({ url }: { url: string }) => {
  return <img src={url} alt={"media"} />;
};
```

**Heading.tsx**

```
export const Heading = ({ text }: { text: string }) => {
  return <h1>{text}</h1>;
};
```

I am expecting App to receive Media component as prop

**App.tsx**

```
export default function App({ media }: { media: ReactNode }) {
  return <div className="App">{media}</div>;
}
```

```
const media = <Media url={"https://picsum.photos/200/300"} />;
const heading = <Heading text={"some heading"} />;

root.render(<App media={media} />); // pass

// Expecting an error here as I am sending a component of type Heading
// But in reality, no error is raised as the prop type is a ReactNode
// A ReactNode accepts any random JSX
root.render(<App media={heading } />);
```

when passing components as props, Is there a way to type props such that TS raises an error on passing in incorrect components?

Answer (score 0):

You can type your `media` prop correctly to achieve this.

Use the `React.FC` generic to let TS know that you expect a component with a prop `url`:

```
export default function App({ media }: { media: React.FC<{ url: string }> }) {
  return <div className="App">{media}</div>;
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-frost-6jxojr?file=/src/App.tsx:252-378)